# Make a post request from https to http

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, cors

Hello i am having trouble making a post request from my https website to my http VPS, whenever i try to make the request i get this error: " POST https://134......:3000/submit net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" (i censored the vps ip).

Is there a solution for that? and how?

frontend code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Simple Form</h1>
  <form id="myForm" action="/submit" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
      
      // Form data
      const formData = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        email: document.getElementById('email').value
      };

      try {
        // Send form data to a specific URL
        const response = await fetch('http://134.....:3000/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Accept':'application/json'
        },
          body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        });

        // Handle response - This could be checking for a successful response or handling errors
        if (response.ok) {
          // Success
          console.log('Form data submitted successfully!');
        } else {
          // Handle errors
          console.error('Error submitting form data:', response.status);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error submitting form data:', error);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());


// Serve static files from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// POST endpoint to handle form submissions
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  const { name, email } = req.body; // Assuming your form has 'name' and 'email' fields
  
  // Here you can process the form data, save to a database, etc.
  // For example, just logging the received data
  console.log('Received data:', { name, email });

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

On my localhost it works...

Comment: Did you make a typo? The code you posted is making the POST request using http, not https

Comment: @smallpepperz if i put https or http it doesnt change anything since the vps's ip doesnt have an ssl certificate

Comment: If you use `http` as the scheme of the target URL, the server doesn't need a TLS cert.

Comment: @jub0bs do you mean  if i put http here? await fetch('http://134.....:3000/submit',

Comment: @warden Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @jub0bs i still get the error

Comment: Do you have HTTPS Everywhere or a similar extension installed in your browser?

Comment: Is your VPS set up to use TLS on port 3000?